# Passing adwords keyword as URL parameter to landing page

Tags: google-ads-api

My site has search functionality that's accessible via a query parameter `q` like this:

```
https://example.com?q=shoes
```

I have many adwords registered for which I'd like to direct users to the my site's search results when they click on the ad. Based on the [documentation](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305348), it seems like this should be possible by using ValueTrack.  In particular, I should be able to set my final URL to something like:

```
https://example.com?q={keyword:socks}
```

The `:socks` is supposed to substitute the default value `socks` for the purposes of previewing an ad. However, whenever I preview my ad through the adwords console, the previews always render the URL literally so that I end up on a landing page with the query string `q={keyword:socks}` for my site search. Even without the `:socks`, the query string still renders literally as `q={keyword}`.

Is this simply an issue with the adwords console? Or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the `{keyword}` ValueTrack parameter supports default values, so you'll have to go with just `q={keyword}`.

As for the preview not working correctly, did you try the "Test" button under "Ad URL options"? It shows you the actual click URL, substituting all parameters where possible:

[image]